# How do I set proxy with baseURL with Nuxt3 and Nitro config

Tags: nuxtjs3, nitro

I'm trying to proxy requests so that when I call `http://localhost:3000/basePath/api` it requests `http://localhost:8080/api`. I'm using [the experimental routerules](https://nitro.unjs.io/config#routerules) from Nitro to do this:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    nitro: {
        routeRules: {
            "api/**": { 
                proxy: {
                    to: "http://localhost:8080/**"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    experimental: {
        payloadExtraction: false
    },
    runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
            backUrl: ''
        }
    },
    app: {
        baseURL: "/basePath",
    }
})
```

The problem is that I want the redirection to be done to  `http://localhost:8080/api` but it's done to `http://localhost:8080/basePath/api`. I don't understand how to keep the `baseURL` in my Nuxt3 config but not to have it in the proxy URL when used with a wildcard.

Answer (score 2):

You can define proxies on the server with  `proxyRequest` and a catch-all route. This will give you all control over the request. That's what route rules seems to do anyway.

Create a file in server/api/[...path].ts

```
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    return proxyRequest(
        event,
        `http://localhost:8080/${event.context.params!.path}`
    )
})
```